# Difference between UIView and UIViewController

Tags: iphone

I’m newbie in iPhone development.I have searched much but couldn’t figure out major difference  between UIView and UIViewController.

Comment: UIView is the visuals, UIViewControllers is the functionality. You should go read about the MVC pattern.

Comment: Have you tried googling?There is a lot of information present there. SO is not your personal search assistant.

Comment: http://iphone-bitcode.blogspot.in/2011/03/uiview-and-uiviewcontroller.html

Comment: You say you searched, but did you actually read the information you found? That would have told you the difference.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

UIView is the object, that we use to display our things, this is the MVC pattern's implementation, you can see your answer in detail here [uiview vs viewcontroller](https://discussions.apple.com/thread/3813430?start=0&tstart=0)
 and here [uivew vs uiview controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1151422/uiview-vs-uiviewcontroller)