# adding a main view in Xcode?

Tags: xcode, view, program-entry-point, viewcontroller

I'm using a book on programming games in xcode to teach myself.
I downloaded some of the programs and tried to make my own codes using them, but i can't figure out how to create a mainview.h or mainview.m
Also how do these differ from view controller?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1151498/1445366

Comment: What book is that you're trying to learn from?

Answer (score 0):

<kbd>command</kbd><kbd>n</kbd> -> Objective-C class -> Next

Class: mainview

Subclass of: UIView

-> Next -> Create

- A view is an area where stuff can be draw (programatically using a view controller or visually in Interface Builder).
- A view controller is a class that that controls how stuff is drawn in a view, it contains all the code and logic).